# Where should 'CreateMap' statements go?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, separation-of-concerns, mvvm

I frequently use AutoMapper to map Model (Domain) objects to ViewModel objects, which are then consumed by my Views, in a Model/View/View-Model pattern.

This involves many 'Mapper.CreateMap' statements, which all must be executed, but must only be executed *once* in the lifecycle of the application.

Technically, then, I should keep them all in a static method somewhere, which gets called from my Application_Start() method (this is an ASP.NET MVC application).

However, it seems wrong to group a lot of different mapping concerns together in one central location.

Especially when mapping code gets complex and involves formatting and other logic.

Is there a better way to organize the mapping code so that it's kept close to the ViewModel that it concerns?

(I came up with one idea - having a 'CreateMappings' method on each ViewModel, and in the BaseViewModel, calling this method on instantiation. However, since the method should only be called *once* in the application lifecycle, it needs some additional logic to cache a list of ViewModel types for which the CreateMappings method has been called, and then only call it when necessary, for ViewModels that aren't in that list.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use profiles, you can place all of your "CreateMap" calls there.  Additionally, you can create a static bootstrapper class that contains your configuration, and have the startup piece just call the bootstrapper.

Comment: But that still doesn't solve the problem of having all the mappings for all the different view-models lumped together, when I'd rather have them somehow related to the classes they apply to.

Answer (score 7):

If you really don't want to use a bootstrapper, then at least a static constructor is an easy way of ensuring your CreateMap is called at most once. (With less messing around and more thread proof than Jonathon's answer.)

```
public class AccountController : Controller 
{
    static AccountController()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Models.User, ViewModels.UserProfile>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Models.User, ViewModels.ChangePassword>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have had no luck with putting the mappings in the static constructor.  I find I have to put them in the instance constructor.

Comment: @AaronLS Oh no.  Do you get an exception or anything like that? Which classes where you using for the constructors and mappings?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the way I'm currently doing it is this:

I add some logic to the constructor of my BaseController, which runs the 'CreateMappings' method, but only once per Controller Type:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{    
    public BaseController()
    {
        if (!controllersWithMappingsCreated.Contains(GetType()))
        {
            CreateMappings();
            controllersWithMappingsCreated.Enqueue(GetType());
        }
    }

    protected virtual void CreateMappings() { }
}
```

In each concrete controller, I use CreateMappings to declare the mappings for all the Models/ViewModels relevant to that controller.

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    public AccountController() : base() { }

    protected override void CreateMappings()
    { 
        Mapper.CreateMap<Models.User, ViewModels.UserProfile>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Models.User, ViewModels.ChangePassword>();
    }
}
```

---

I also found some interesting alternatives involving Attributes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494167/how-to-configure-automapper-once-per-appdomain/1498193#1498193) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494167/how-to-configure-automapper-once-per-appdomain/1690811#1690811), however they strike me as a bit overcomplicated.

Comment: I'd still have a static bootstrapper class, so you can unittest your mappings.

Comment: Nice work. But what is the `controllersWithMappingsCreated` in the `BaseController`?